How to Trigger 404 On Website when not being logged in?
I am new to web development and want to achieve the following setup:

Login page where a user can log in using admin admin as username password (login.html)
He should then be redirected to a homepage (homepage.html)
When entering the homepage into the URL and the user is logged in (cached?) the homepage should appear normally (trigger onload event).
When entering the homepage into the URL and the user is not logged in it should return a 404 and throw on onerror event, no onload event (compare with event when opening https://google.com/404).

I am using node.js so far with the following structure:

project/public/login.html
project/public/homepage.html
project/server.js

The following code:

login.html
homepage.html
server.js

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" required>
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" required>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

            if (username === 'admin' && password === 'admin') {
                localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'true');
                window.location.href = 'homepage.html';
            } else {
                alert('Invalid credentials');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Homepage</h1>
    <button id="logoutButton">Logout</button>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
            if (loggedIn !== 'true') {
                window.onerror();
            }
        });

        window.onerror = function() {
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
            document.write('<h1>404 Not Found</h1>');
            return false; // Prevents the default handling.
        };

        document.getElementById('logoutButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
            window.location.href = 'login.html';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 27182;

// Serve static files from 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Middleware to check login status
function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Checking login status...');
    // Simulate checking login state with a custom header
    const loggedIn = req.headers['x-logged-in'] === 'true';
    if (!loggedIn) {
        res.status(404).send('Not Fund'); // Send 404 status code
    } else {
        next(); // Proceed to the next middleware/route handler
    }
}

// Route for the homepage (restricted)
app.get('/homepage.html', checkLogin, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'homepage.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

I start the server using node server.js.
Now when I am logged in I can open the homepage, and when I am logged out and enter the URL of the homepage I also get to a 404 website, but I don't get the wanted error event. How can I implement this properly/where is my mistake?
For clarity: I need to trigger an onerror event and no onload event for another task I am implementing this demo for.
Thank you!

In this situation it would be more appropriate with the response code 403 Forbidden "The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it." That said, the response codes used in the HTTP protocol has nothing to do this the events that are triggered on the page when it loads -- a HTML page with a client error code (like 404 or 403) is also loaded successfully in the browser just like any other page with the 200 OK code.
